# Apple Command Line Tools AND XCode For Open Source Compile/Build?

Tags: xcode, gcc, clang, xcode-command-line-tools

I don't use XCode but have it "left over" from when it was the path to installing the Apple Command Line Tools - which I do use for compiling/building other software. I now seem to have both XCode and Apple Command Line Tools and don't really care to continue updating XCode every few months (huge download).

My 2 questions before deleting XCode:

1. Will Apple Command Line Tools remain on my machine and usable for open source build/compile if I trash XCode?
2. Will I lose some useful functionality I don't know about elsewhere (if I really never do use XCode)?

Question 2.5: Is this a safe delete?

[This post was similar but unanswered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959384/how-are-apples-command-line-tool-binaries-organized)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is required when building MacVim from Homebrew. The Command Line Tools alone are insufficient. I reinstalled Xcode...